# Database trigger: comparison of column value with empty variable

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird, model-driven-development

I'm preparing for an exam on Model-Driven Development. I came across a specific database trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tManager_bi
FOR Manager BEFORE INSERT AS
DECLARE VARIABLE v_company_name CHAR(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT M.company
  FROM   Manager M
  WHERE  M.nr = NEW.reports_to
  INTO  :v_company_name;

  IF (NOT(NEW.company = v_company_name))
    THEN EXCEPTION eReportsNotOwnCompany;
END
```

This trigger is designed to prevent input in which a manager reports to an outside manager, i.e. one that is not from the same company. The corresponding OCL constraint is:

```
context Manager
   inv: self.company = self.reports_to.company
```

The relevant table looks like (simplified):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Manager
(
  nr INTEGER NOT NULL,
  company VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  reports_to INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (nr),
  FOREIGN KEY (reports_to) REFERENCES Manager (nr)
);
```

The textbook says that this trigger will also work correctly when the newly inserted manager doesn't report to anyone (i.e. `NEW.reports_to` is `NULL`), and indeed, upon testing, it does work correctly.

But I don't understand this. If `NEW.reports_to` is `NULL`, that would mean the variable `v_company_name` will be empty (uninitialized? `NULL`?), which would then mean the comparison `NEW.company = v_company_name` would return `false`, causing the exception to be thrown, right?

What am I missing here?

(The SQL shown is supposed to be SQL:2003 compliant. The MDD tool is Cathedron, which uses Firebird as an RDBMS.)

Comment: _"This trigger is designed to prevent input in which a manager reports to himself."_  Are you sure?  That trigger seems written to prevent input in which a manager reports to someone at another company.

Comment: @pilcrow Good catch! Edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the fact that when you compare `NULL` to `NULL` (or to any other value), the answer is `NULL`, not `false`. And negation of `NULL` is still `NULL`, so in the `IF` statement the `ELSE` part would fire (if there is one).

I suggest you read the [Firebird Null Guide](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nullguide.html) for better understanding it all.

Comment: So, just to be sure: the value that is put into the variable `v_company_name` after the select that returns an empty table is `NULL`, not some (other) kind of undefined value?

Comment: When the select statement returns empty resultset, then the value of the `v_company_name` remains unchanged (it is not set to NULL!). So it would have the value it had before the select statement is executed, which in this case should be NULL.

Comment: You're absolutely right. From your link: "If you declare a variable in a stored procedure or trigger, its value is undefined and its state is `NULL` from the moment of creation until some value is assigned to it."

Answer (score 2):

AS. Making this answer for the sake of code highlighting.

You might want to modify your trigger to respond to both updates and inserts.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tManager_bi
FOR Manager BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE AS
...
```

You also may avoid hand-writing the trigger at all, if you do not need that specific exception identifier.

You may just use SQL Check Constraint for that

```
alter table Manager  
    add constraint chk_ManagerNotRespondsOneself
        CHECK ( NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT * FROM Manager M
          WHERE  M.nr = reports_to
            AND  M.company = company 
        ) )
```

Specifying custom exceptions over CHECK constraints does not look possible now... http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1852